# adding prefix to words in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a List of Strings and i want to compare every i write in an EditText with that list. If there is a match then i have to add a "-" character as a prefix for that word.

I am using a TextWatcher and this is my code so far:

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String tmp = s.toString();
        words = tmp.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for (Iterator iterator = myList.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                String str = (String) iterator.next();
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(words[i])) {
                    if (!words[i].contains("-")) {
                        tmp = tmp.replace(words[i], "-" + words[i]);

                    }
                    editMain.setText(tmp);
                    editMain.setSelection(tmp.length());

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It works but if i type the same word twice in my EditText, the first ocurrence gets two "--".

For example:

hello this is -android (works ok)

hello this is --android -android (does not work ok)

And the desired result should be:

hello this is -android android (because the repeated word already exists)

Any help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Maybe you mean android word has already been found and then it should not be prefixed by a -.

If that's the case, just remove a mathcing word from mylist. For that use a listIterator.

Comment: Thank you Snicolas, that is the case and your solution works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

try to set a counter. If the counter is bigger than 1, then don't write the -